# Laravel Pagination To Certain Section

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-8

Guys
I'm using Laravel's default pagination with bootstrap as its styling framework.
I want to direct my page to certain html section after I click the pagination link, so far I only know how to paginate like the following codes:

Controller:

```
$data = Products::paginate(9);
return view('index', ['data' => $data]);
```

Blade:

```
{{ $data->links() }}
```

So, I want to direct my page to a certain section in html everytime I clicked the pagination link button. how can I achieve that?

I'm sorry for my poor explanation, hit me up if you need more detail.

Thank You

Comment: do you want change list and paginate without refresh page with ajax??

Comment: is it simple? can I combine it with ajax for search?

Comment: yes. i can explain how to use ajax in pagination

Comment: It would be really helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make a blade file like this:
pagination.blade.php

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
        <li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link disabled">قبلی</a>
        </li>
    @else
        <li class="paginate_button page-item previous">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link" data-page="{{ $paginator->currentPage()-1 }}">pre</a>
        </li>
    @endif
    @foreach ($elements as $element)
        @if (is_string($element))
            <li class="paginate_button page-item active">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link" >{{ $element }}</a>
            </li>
        @endif
        @if (is_array($element))
            @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                    <li class="paginate_button page-item active"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                @else
                    <li class="paginate_button page-item "><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link" data-page="{{ $page }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
    {{-- next page  --}}
    @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
        <li class="paginate_button page-item next ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link" data-page="{{ $paginator->currentPage()+1 }}">next</a>
        </li> 
    @else
        <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="disabled">بعدی</a>
        </li>
    @endif
</ul>
@endif
```

then create a blade file like this:
table.blade.php

```
  @if(isset($permissions))
@php
    $paginator=$permissions;
@endphp
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            heaers tags
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-data">
        
        @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
            tr tags
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@endif

<div class="col-md-12">
    {{ $paginator->links('sections.pagination') }}
</div>
```

then in controller method:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $permissions=Permission::paginate(5);
    if($request->ajax()){
        return view('sections.table',compact('permissions'));
    }
    return view('permission.index',compact('permissions'));
}
```